# How do I match 2 columns data and when a match is found copy a 3rd column of data to a 4th blank column

Tags: excel-2007, matching

Example:

```
Column A        Column B       Column C     Column D
90516-9240       107461                     107461
90516-9574       124174                     107461
90516-9665       143064                     124174
90516-9268       148725                     124174
90516-9267       161747                     128986
90516-9586       171964                     133339
```

where if any number in column B matches any number in column D then the number from column A will fill to column C

so it would look like this:

```
Column A        Column B       Column C     Column D
90516-9240       107461        90516-9240   107461
90516-9574       124174        90516-9240   107461
90516-9665       143064        90516-9574   124174
90516-9268       148725        90516-9574   124174
90516-9267       161747                     128986
90516-9586       171964                     133339
```

What is the simplest formula I can use to do this.

Comment: Please clarify the contents of columns C and D, as your formatting is messed up.

Comment: I've just added an edit suggestion and cleaned up the tables. Sitting waiting for approval.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a lookup using Index/Match. Assuming row 1 has labels, start in C2 with

```
=index(A:A,match(D2,B:B,0))
```

If you swap columns A and B, you can use a Vlookup():

```
=vlookup(D2,$A$1:$B$1000,2,false)
```

Copy down.